# Using different dataframes to fit estimator and as input of scoring function in cross_val_score and GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, scoring

When I use cross_val_score

```
cross_val_score(randomForestEstimator.fit(X,y), X, y, cv=3, scoring=CustomScoring)
```

or GridSearchCV

```
GridSearchCV(randomForestEstimator, parameters, cv=3, verbose=3, scoring=CustomScoring)
```

with a custom scoring function - having the signature `scorer(estimator, X, y)` - the *same* set of features i.e. dataframe is used to fit the estimator AND as scorer's input.

But the problem is that I do *not* want my estimator to "see" some columns, which are needed later by my scorer to compute the score. So my question is: how can I use different set of features (or dataframes) for fitting my estimator and as scorer input?